# dayClick is not working on Android device for an application made with phonegap

Tags: android, cordova, click, fullcalendar

I am working on a mobile application built for iOS and Android device using Phonegap where I have used ‘fullCalendar’ to display date in month format.
While preparing the calender, I have define ‘dayClick’ event so that we can click on any date. Where as it works fine on browser, but on Android device when I tested, the dayClick event was not working.
It never gets called.
Below is my code block defining the calendar options.

```
options = {
        header: {
                left: "",
                center: 'title',
        },
        gotoDate: defaultDate,
        selectable: true,
        //Triggers when a date is clicked
        dayClick: function(date, allDay, jsEvent, view) {
            alert(date);
}
```

};

Please suggest any to make it workable on touch devices.

Comment: Have you tried using eventClick? http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/mouse/eventClick/

Comment: Event click is related with events I guess.... whereas, I dont have any events.